What is the best package to use to create a bespoke boundary around the page text on most pages of a book?
\documentclass[english,11pt,twosided,openright]{book}

\usepackage{amsmath}%
\usepackage{hhline}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage[paperheight=180mm,paperwidth=140mm,asymmetric,bindingoffset=12.5mm,left=12.5mm,right=12.5mm,top=8mm,showframe,showcrop]{geometry}
\usepackage[a4,cam,center]{crop}%
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter heading}
\section{A confusion among four drawing packages}

1. I would like to have one rectangle - similar to the inner complete rectangle - to be coloured, say grey, and clear the page text by 4pt all around on most pages.

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent 2. Are the four packages: geometry, showframe, crop and eso-pic truly independent or not; I cannot make it out?


\vspace{18pt}
Some text to fill the page or nearly so ome text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so ome text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so.


\end{document}


I don't understand what you aim for at all, but think, you don't want to use the crop package here because you don't want to set up the bleed, do you? After all, the geometry package could do the same with setting the right options. Rather, I understand that you want to have a rectangle on every page. Could you maybe post an image of how the output should look like?

why the down vote? the question could be improved by clarifying the question before or after including the code, but I don't see it deserves voting down.

off-topic: there is no twosided option. probably you mean twoside?

@JasperHabicht A rectangle around the text - excluding the header and footer - as in the answer below. Can the geometry package do that - given the correct settings?

@keith77777 Why should the geometry package do that? It's aim is to set the geometry of the page, not to draw boxes. But there are different other packages that can do that.

My original answer provided code to put a filled rectangle behind the text block. In response the the OP's request (see comments), the current version also provides code to frame the text block1.
Syntax2:

\FillBehind places a filled rectangle behind the text block on this and subsequent pages;
\FrameBehind places a frame around (and behind) the text block on this and subsequent pages;
\PlainPage*+[] takes an optional star, an optional plus and an optional argument:

* -> remove specified background from this and subsequent pages;
+ -> remove specified background from the next page but one and subsequent pages;
neither * nor + -> remove specified background from the next and subsequent pages;
the optional argument specifies the type of thing to remove and should be either Frame or Fill. The default is Frame.


\FrameWd is a LaTeX length which determines the thickness of the frame.
This version also makes things fit, though the methods used are probably not ones you want to use in your real document. Nonetheless, you should look for bad boxes and should also read what geometry writes in the log file. You should adjust things somehow so things fit the page. For this example, I did it partly by modifying geometry's settings and partly by rewording.

Output2:

\documentclass[english,11pt,twoside,openright]{book}
% ateb: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/732674/
% addaswyd o gwestiwn keith77777: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/732667/
\newlength\FrameWd
\setlength\FrameWd{2pt}
\newlength\thismarginwidth
\usepackage{xcolor}
% modified settings to fit paper
\usepackage[paperheight=180mm,paperwidth=140mm,includehead,marginparwidth=20pt,marginparsep=5pt,verbose,showframe,asymmetric,bindingoffset=12.5mm,left=12.5mm,right=12.5mm,top=8mm,headheight=11pt,showcrop]{geometry}

\NewDocumentCommand \FillBehind { O {blue!10!gray!10} }
{%
  \AddToHook{shipout/background}[FillBehind]
  {%
    \ifodd\value{page}\let\thismarginwidth\oddsidemargin\else\let\thismarginwidth\evensidemargin\fi
    \put (\dimexpr 1in+\thismarginwidth-4pt,\dimexpr -\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-1in+4pt) {%
      \begingroup
      \color{#1}%
      \vrule height 0pt depth \dimexpr \textheight + 8pt width \dimexpr \textwidth + 8pt
      \endgroup
    }%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand \FrameBehind { O {blue!10!gray} }
{%
  \AddToHook{shipout/background}[FrameBehind]
  {%
    \ifodd\value{page}\let\thismarginwidth\oddsidemargin\else\let\thismarginwidth\evensidemargin\fi
    \put (\dimexpr 1in+\thismarginwidth-4pt -\FrameWd,\dimexpr -\topmargin-\headheight-\headsep-1in+4pt +\FrameWd) {%
      \begingroup
      \let\fboxrule\FrameWd
      \color{#1}%
      \boxframe{\dimexpr \textwidth + 8pt + 2\FrameWd}{0pt}{\dimexpr \textheight + 8pt + 2\FrameWd}%
      \endgroup
    }%
  }%
}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected_nopar:Npn \__keith_empty_page:n #1
{
  \hook_gremove_code:nn { shipout/background } { #1 Behind }
}

\NewDocumentCommand \PlainPage { s t {+} O {Frame} }
{
  \IfBooleanTF {#1} {
    \__keith_empty_page:n { #3 }
  }{
    \IfBooleanTF{#2}{
      \hook_gput_next_code:nn { shipout/after}
      {
        \hook_gput_next_code:nn { shipout/after}
        {
          \__keith_empty_page:n { #3 }
        }
      }
    }{
      \hook_gput_next_code:nn { shipout/after}
      {
        \__keith_empty_page:n { #3 }
      }
    }
  }
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\chapter{A chapter heading}
% modified wording to fit
\section{A confusion concerning four drawing packages}

\FrameBehind
1. I would like to have one rectangle - similar to the inner complete rectangle - to be coloured, say grey, and clear the page text by 4pt all around on most pages.

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent 2. Are the four packages: geometry, showframe, crop and eso-pic truly independent or not; I cannot make it out?


\vspace{18pt}
Some text to fill the page or nearly so ome text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so ome text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so.

\PlainPage+

\chapter{A chapter heading}
\section{A confusion concerning four drawing packages}

\FillBehind
1. I would like to have one rectangle - similar to the inner complete rectangle - to be coloured, say grey, and clear the page text by 4pt all around on most pages.

\vspace{4pt}
\noindent 2. Are the four packages: geometry, showframe, crop and eso-pic truly independent or not; I cannot make it out?


\vspace{18pt}
Some text to fill the page or nearly so ome text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so ome text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so some text to fill the page or nearly so.


\end{document}

1Note to any Powers-That-Be who happen to have nothing better to do than read footnotes: I really tried not to use expl3 for this, but finally gave up in frustration. It was either expl3 or \expandafter. I chose the former. I think it should be doable using lthooks's 2e interface. I'm sure it is doable with the 2e stuff. It is far less simple with the 2e versiona.
2This answer implements a policy known (at least to this footnote) as ARRF. The complete policy unfortunately exceeds SE's limit, but can be summarised as follows: All Rants to be Relegated to Footnotes. This footnote was brought to you by the Footnote Appreciation Society.
3Because it requires a magician to figure out magick's eccentric syntax and the so-called documentation is damned if it will divulge one drop of secret lore to the unitiated: magick <image 1> <image 2> <image 3> +append <output file>
aMostly because I can't figure out how to expand an optional argument with \ExpandArgs.

Thanks for that. Entirely my fault, but it was the boundary of the rectangle I wanted to show - not the fill, and your syntax is far too advanced for me to improvise. Could you edit your answer, please, to achieve this result.

@keith77777 please see edit

Many thanks for the update - perfect.
